# FPDF - Unable to save a copy to the file system

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to generate a PDF document. I want to both save a copy to the file system for our records and output a copy for the user to the browser. For some reason I can't get the file to save to the file system. Can anyone see what it may be? The folder has permissions set to 777 so that shouldn't be the issue.

```
        <?php 

    include('./fpdf181/fpdf.php'); 
    include('./FPDI-1.6.1/fpdi.php'); 

    //get user's name
    $name = $_GET['name'];

    // initiate FPDI 
    $pdf = new FPDI(); 
    // add a page 
    $pdf->AddPage(); 
    // set the sourcefile 
    $pdf->setSourceFile('../uploads/certificates/IBA-Certificate-Coaching-Course.pdf'); 
    // import page 1 
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
    // use the imported page as the template 
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0,210, 180, true); 

    // now write some text above the imported page 
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0); 

    //member's name
    $pdf->SetXY(88, 85); 
    $pdf->Write(0, $name); 

    //current date
    $date = date("m/d/Y");
    $pdf->SetXY(35, 140); 
    $pdf->Write(0, $date); 

    //save copy to file system
    $pdf->Output('./certificates/certificate-of-coaching-readiness.pdf','F');

    //output a copy to the user
    $pdf->Output('certificate-of-coaching-readiness.pdf', 'D'); 


    ?>
```

Comment: I think you have the two arguments of `$pdf->Output()` mixed up. Swap them around.

Comment: I tried that earlier, just tried again, no joy.

Comment: Well, it seems the documentation and the PHP code contradict each other on the order of the arguments of `$pdf->Output()`. Since you tried it both ways, and they both don't work, something else must cause your problems. Are you sure the path and permissions are correct? Which user made the directory? Sometimes this can make a difference (SELinux).